# google closure compiler executed by npx/node/npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-closure-compiler, npx

I am trying to compile my client js files with the google closure compiler, and it works well with java:

```
java -jar node_modules/google-closure-compiler/compiler.jar --js=public/**.js
```

However, if I try to do the same through node or npx (as documented [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-closure-compiler)), I always get the same error:

```
npx google-closure-compiler --js=public/**.js
node .\node_modules\google-closure-compiler\cli.js --js=public/**.js
```

Both return the same error

```
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\myfolder\public\**.js']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'D:\\myfolder\\public\\**.js' }
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
    at Ird (D:\myfolder\node_modules\google-closure-compiler\jscomp.js:5364:88)
    at Drd (D:\myfolder\node_modules\google-closure-compiler\jscomp.js:7747:257)
...
```

The path `D:\\myfolder\\public\\` is correct

It would be very handy if I could compile all files without installing JRE.

Comment: Can you verify the version of the compiler you are using?

Comment: Just did a fresh npm install, same problem and it seems to be 20180910.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a windows specific bug in the cli script. It [looks like you have already reported it](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler-npm/issues/108).